# How to fix g++ error while parsing template member function of dependent type?

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I have a template class `class Map<typename Line, typename itype, typename ipos>` and I'm trying to call a templated member of class `Line` from a member of `Map` :

```
template<class Line, typename itype, int ipos>
class Map
{
public:
  itype getIndex(Line &line)
  {
    return line.get<ipos>();
  }
};
```

and I get the g++ error :

> error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
>
> return line.get < ipos > ();

Compiles fine under VS12; g++ version is 5.1.

I thought the inside of functions was not parsed until instantiation, apparently I'm very wrong. How can I get around that error?

Maybe I was too influenced by VC++'s "whatever compiles is correct" style...

Comment: Try `return line.template get<ipos>();`

Comment: @RSahu thank you, I didn't even know the template keyword was supposed to be used that way ! Which is why I couldn't find the duplicate topic...